# Difference between new int[]{} or just {}

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Is there a significant difference between these two lines of code?

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3}
int[] array = {1,2,3}
```

If I had to guess, the same constructor is called implicitly in the second version, making them identical.

Edit:
[This question was explored previously here but with default values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348818/is-it-faster-or-better-to-declare-an-array-inline-in-java) My question regarded the initialization of an array with non-default values.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the byte-code and see if there are any noticeable difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, I did de-compile the class with following methods

```
public void arrayTest1(){
    int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3};
}

public void arrayTest2(){
    int[] array = {1,2,3};  
}
```

Here is the result related to them.

```
  public void arrayTest1();
    Code:
       0: iconst_3
       1: newarray       int
       3: dup
       4: iconst_0
       5: iconst_1
       6: iastore
       7: dup
       8: iconst_1
       9: iconst_2
      10: iastore
      11: dup
      12: iconst_2
      13: iconst_3
      14: iastore
      15: astore_1
      16: return

  public void arrayTest2();
    Code:
       0: iconst_3
       1: newarray       int
       3: dup
       4: iconst_0
       5: iconst_1
       6: iastore
       7: dup
       8: iconst_1
       9: iconst_2
      10: iastore
      11: dup
      12: iconst_2
      13: iconst_3
      14: iastore
      15: astore_1
      16: return
```

Both the statements essentially look the same de-compiled.

Comment: Thank you! This is good to know. This was one of the comments on my original post: "Have you tried disassembling the byte-code and see if there are any noticeable difference? – Veera". Is this what you did? How is this done?

Comment: [javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) is provided by Java distribution that allows your disassemble the byte-code. In this case, I had run with -c option

Comment: Thanks [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) for adding a more broken down piece of code.